# Error fetching MySQL array using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to convert my application from the old `mysql` syntax to `PDO` and it's been a real pain. Right now i'm having trouble as it seems like the same query using `PDO` is coming up empty as one that returned a full array using `mysql_fetch_array`

Here is the code for one of my functions:

```
//Get all contacts from DB
public function getContacts($regId) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT contacts FROM gcm_users WHERE gcm_regid = '$regId'";
        $resource = $this->db->query($sql);
        //$resource = mysql_query("SELECT contacts FROM gcm_users WHERE gcm_regid = '$regId'");      
        $resultArray = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $resultArray[0];
        }

    catch (SQLException $e) {
        $output = 'Error fetching contacts: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The original `mysql_query` which worked fine is commented out. The error i'm currently receiving with this is:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcm\db_functions.php on line 197
```

Which leads to my

```
$result = $resultArray[0];
```

I looked up the error and it seems to be because the `$resultArray` is empty. I'm not used to using the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`, so i'm assuming the problem is in there somewhere.

Comment: Why did you assume an indexed `[0]` array, instead of an associative `["contacts"]`? And why aren't you using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) to verify your assumptions?

Comment: Is `$result` meant to be a single contact, or an array of contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, which retrieves your result set row into an associative array (that is, an array with named elements like `$resultArray['contacts']`.

You seem to want a numbered array. Use PDO::FETCH_NUM instead to get that.